# Code to check if a list of numbers is in arithmetic progression or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following is the code to check if a list of items is in arithmetic progression or not.

```
def ap():
    l=[int(x) for x in list(input("Enter the list: "))]
    diff=l[1]-l[0]
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if not ( l[i+1]-l[i]==diff):
           return False
    return True
```

When I am executing the above code, it is working fine, but If I am modifying the code and don't use the "not" keyword it is returning true in all the cases.
Following is the code:

```
def ap():
    l=[int(x) for x in list(input("Enter the list: "))]
    diff=l[1]-l[0]
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if (l[i+1]-l[i]==diff):
            return True
    return False
```

Can someone please help me to figure out where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example input?

Comment: The first code is *"if any two values are __not__ matching, the whole sequence is false."* The second one is *"if any two values __are__ matching, the whole sequence is true."* Very different, no?

Comment: of course it would not be working properly. It *short-circuits*. As soon as a difference is found that satisfies the condition, `True` is returned without checking them all. And in fact, the first condition that is checked is the one used to define `diff` so every series fed will `return True`

Comment: @roganjosh You were right on the money about the downvoting thing though. I feel SO is turning a bit *too snobby*. This is not a `-3` question

Comment: In the second snippet, at `i == 0` you are performing the check `l[1]-l[0] == l[1] - l[0]`. This is why the function returns `True`. However, this is not the actual problem - the first snippet checks if _all_ intervals have the same diff, the second one checks if _any_ interval has the same diff.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I don't know, any self-inflicted problem that could be figured out by following what the code does with pen and paper is not a great question for SO methinks.

Comment: @deceze Without the *pen-and-paper* solvable problems, SO would look like the list of the [millenium problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems). And there is a gap between *not great* and *-3*

Comment: @deceze this code is obviously wrong but on first inspection, to me at least, it looks like it's a perfect inversion of logic. I'm not sure it deserves all the downvotes. It's far above some of the crap that's posted here, the OP made an attempt and it's not terribly misguided.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis *Applicability to other programmers* is a big criterion for SO questions. Will this question ever be applicable to anyone else? Will anyone else ever *find* this problem given the title and terse description? … Probably not. → Downvote. → Lower visibility in searches. → Better discoverability of good content.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does.  You get the difference between the first two elements, and then in your loop, the first step will check if the difference between the first two elements is the same, which it will always be.  So, it will always return true in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. So, now I have modified the code and am checking from the 3rd element, and it's working fine now.

Comment: should start with 2nd element I think.

Comment: Hi Garr, sorry it was a typo. I did start checking from the 2nd element